# Enable Networking in VMWare

Tags: 10.04, networking, internet, vmware

I just got myself an Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop CD. I pop it into my DVD drive (on my laptop which has Windows 7), run VMWare, install Ubuntu using Easy Install. So far, so good.

But, now, internet does not work in Ubuntu desktop.

How do I enable networking (both connected and wireless). 
[image]

**EDIT**

I do not know what happened or how it got fixed. But, it is now fixed. However, Empathy IM client does not work although, I am able to browse the internet (which is what I wanted in the first place!).

Comment: @hhlp: The tag should be vmware and **not** wmware. Can you please map it to the appropriate tag. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Go to ‘Virtual Machine’ in menu and press ‘Install VMware Tools’ option. This will mount the ISO file to CD drive as ‘VMware Tools’.

2) Extract the tar.gz file to local folder.

3) Open terminal (  Application –> Accessories –> Terminal) and go to the extracted folder in above step.

4) Once you locate the vmware-install.pl script

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175876/how-do-i-fix-my-vms-network-connection-if-it-seems-to-be-running-ok-from-the-hos) problem may be related to yours.

Comment: Thanks! However, with Easy Install, VMWare Tools is already installed. I did a reinstall of it and restarted the system too. It still did NOT work.

Comment: check the added link

Comment: Thanks for the links! Unfortunately, I am a newbie with Linux (I installed it, so that I can learn Python!). I did check out the steps present in that SO question and...none of them works. For instance, my /var/logs/kern.log does not have entries about renaming eth0 to eth1.

Comment: Hmm as I google I seem a lot of problems with vmware and ubuntu 10.4. I would try Virtualbox, it's free and better/faster IMHO anyways. Go download at http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads In computers some problems are just better to be avoided than solved :P

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that i had to reset the vmWare network configuration, for that you have to start the Virtual Network Editor: vmnetcfg.exe and to press the button: Restore Default localized in the bottom left corner of the dialog and that's all.